# what is this meaning "assert(value[, message])"

Tags: javascript

This is a javascript function `assert(value[, message])`.

I want to know what is difference between `assert(value[, message])` and `assert(value, message)`.

Comment: First one is signature. Optional parameters are shown in square brackets.

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_value_message
thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

**The square brackets are used when writing function descriptions to indicate that the parameters are optional.**

In the case of `assert(value[, message])` the first parameter, `value`, is required. If you try to call the function without it -- `assert();` -- the function will not work or will throw an error. The second parameter, `message`, is optional. You can call the function with just the first parameter -- `assert(value);` -- and it will work correctly.

If the function is shown as `assert(value, message)` then both parameters are required and they both must be given in order for the function to execute as expected or without throwing an error.

Comment: thank you very much